# Why I obtain this .dll file into the project root folder of a .NET project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, dll

I am not so into **.NET** and I am finding the following problem. Into my solution I have a project named something like **MyProjectUtilities**. I am using Visual Studio 2017.

When I build this project it is creating a **MyProjectUtilities.XmlSerializers.dll** file inside the root folder of this project. This file have not to be here because it creates problem when I publish my solution. This strange behavior happen from a couple of days and I don't know why because I have not worked on this specific problem.

What could be the cause of this strange behavior? How can I try to analyze the situation?

Comment: Is "MyProjectUtilities" a solution or a project? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/solutions-and-projects-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Comment: @MindSwipe a project into a solution

Comment: So "MyProjectUtilities" is a .NET class library?

Comment: Can you check Properties -> Build -> Generate serialization assembly option? Make it to off

Answer (score 0):

Projects output path is set on the projects properties. Right click project name on the solution explorer and select properties. Select build on the right side panel and check the output path. This defines where the project will store the .dll it creates.